# is "over the past years" a natural sounding expression?

Tags: phrases, expressions, word-usage, phrase-usage

I have heard "over the past few years" or "over past years", but I just read a document that said "X, Y and Z have been beneficial over the past years".  This strikes me as wrong, but I found the expression used here:

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/uk-trade-performance-over-the-past-years-trade-and-investment-analytical-papers-topic-3-of-18

Am I wrong and the phrase is fine?

Comment: In AmE:Of the three (over the past few years, over past years, over the past years), the one that seems most odd and unlikely is "over past years".  "over the past years sounds not so odd, but still unlikely.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Over+past+years%2Cover+the+past+years%2Cover+the+past+few+years&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1940&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2COver%20past%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bover%20past%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOver%20past%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cover%20the%20past%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bover%20the%20past%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOver%20the%20past%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cover%20the%20past%20few%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bover%20the%20past%20few%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOver%20the%20past%20few%20years%3B%2Cc0

Comment: can you post this as an answer so I can select it and mark the question resolved please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the three, "over past years" sounds the most odd, and least likely to be used.  Google ngram bears this out:

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Over+past+years%2Cover+the+past+years%2Cover+the+past+few+years&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1940&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2COver%20past%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bover%20past%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOver%20past%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cover%20the%20past%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bover%20the%20past%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOver%20the%20past%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cover%20the%20past%20few%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bover%20the%20past%20few%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOver%20the%20past%20few%20years%3B%2Cc0